# Javascript / jquery - site not loading at all in IE7 and Google Adsense not loading at all in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

For some reason the following site is not loading at all in IE7 and the Google AdSense are not loading at all in IE8.  The site loads fine in all browsers otherwise, including IE9, Firefox, Chrome.

The site url is: http://www.dog-health-guide.org

Using the F12 Developer tools console in IE, I see there's a Javascript error that IE is throwing (screenshot below) when in IE7 Standards document mode:

[image: JS Error in IE7 Document Mode from F12 Developer Tools]

Any ideas about how I can go about to troubleshoot this to figure out why it's crapping out in IE7 and IE8 greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not start with a validator check?...you have a lot of invalid html. [w3validator](http://validator.w3.org)

Comment: In general, I would assume jQuery UI 1.8.18 needs latest jQuery - 1.7.  your 1.3.2 is really old. Try upgrading your jQuery.

Comment: I'd sub in the non-minified jQuery script and see where the error is.